# WPF Win10 Disable Autoplay

Tags: wpf, autoplay, wndproc

My program is capturing when a USB-devices is plugged in/out and does what it is supposed to do.

There is one annoying thing : explorer opens a window. Guess auto-play is the culprit. Disabling auto-play on that machine entirely is not an option so it has to be disabled just when this application is running.

I found numerous articles on how to do this by capturing the windows message. Which let to the following code, which is compiling and triggering on the arrival of windowsmessages. But unfortunalty the QUeryCancelAutoPlay seems never being called.

```
protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
   HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
   source.AddHook(WndProc);
}

private UInt32 queryCancelAutoPlay = 0;

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);


private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    if (queryCancelAutoPlay == 0)
    {
       queryCancelAutoPlay = RegisterWindowMessage("QueryCancelAutoPlay");
    }

    if (msg == queryCancelAutoPlay)
    {
        return (IntPtr)1;
    }
    return IntPtr.Zero;
  }
```

Any thoughts ?
I develop this on a win10 machine.

Comment: Seems or is it really never called? Try adding a break in debug.
Also, the application needs to be the Top window, otherwise it won't receive the messages.

I myself have struggled with cancelling the autoplay event in the WndProc function. My solution was to add handled = true; just before returning the (IntPtr)1

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class MainWindow : NavigationWindow
    {
        public int queryCancelAutoPlay = 0;
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnClosing(e);
            MainWindow_Closing(this, e);
        }

        protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
            MainWindow_SourceInitialized(this, e);
        }

        private void MainWindow_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Initialize MainWindow");
            IntPtr windowHandle = (new WindowInteropHelper(this)).Handle;
            HwndSource src = HwndSource.FromHwnd(windowHandle);
            src.AddHook((WndProc));
        }

        private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            //if the QueryCancelAutoPlay message id has not been registered...

            if (queryCancelAutoPlay == 0)
            {
                queryCancelAutoPlay = RegisterWindowMessage("QueryCancelAutoPlay");
                Debug.WriteLine("cancel autoplay registered. msg id: " + queryCancelAutoPlay.ToString());
            }
            //if the window message id equals the QueryCancelAutoPlay message id
            if (msg == queryCancelAutoPlay)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Autoplay cancelled");
                queryCancelAutoPlay = 0;
                handled = true;
                return new IntPtr(1);
            }
            return new IntPtr(msg);

        }

        private void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Close MainWindow");
            HwndSource source = (HwndSource)HwndSource.FromVisual(this);
            source.RemoveHook(new HwndSourceHook(this.WndProc));
        }

    }
```